# Associative functions of real numbers with 1 and 0

Tags: associativity

What are the binary functions $F$ of the real numbers, possibly taking an open subset or including infinity, that have an identity element and a zero element and are associative? I know that $F:[-\infty,\infty)^2\to\mathbb R, F(x,y)=x+y+m$ works with identity $-m$ and idempotent $-\infty$, and similarly $F:{\mathbb R}^2\to\mathbb R , F(x,y)=mxy$, but are there any others?

Comment: Take any bijection $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and define $F(x,y)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)+\phi(y))$. (Also, instead of adding you can use multiplication.) Yours are two special cases $\phi(x)=x+m$ and $\phi(x)=mx$ (for $m\ne 0$).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there are any others, or if those cases are the only nontrivial ones?

Comment: Yes. The most general you can go is this: (a) Take a set $S$ of cardinality $|\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$. (b) Equip it with a structure of a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), to become $(S,\circ)$ (c) Take any bijection $\phi:\mathbb R\to S$. (d) Define $x\circ y:=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)\circ\phi(y))$. Non-isomorphic monoids of size $\mathfrak c$ would give you substantially different structures on $\mathbb R$. For example, carry $\oplus$ ("xor" operation) on $2=\{0,1\}$ onto $2^{\aleph_0}$ component-wise and use any bijection of $\mathbb R$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: (The above monoid is substantially different from both examples you are mentioning because (for its zero element $e$) it satisfies $x\oplus x=e$ for every element $x\in\mathbb R$ i.e. it is a torsion monoid.) Another (somewhat degenerate) case is to choose any $e\in\mathbb R$ and define $x\circ y:=e$.

Comment: That's great, thanks! How do you know that's the most general you can go?

Comment: Because for any such monoid $(\mathbb R,\circ)$ it is of that form for $S=\mathbb R, \phi=Id_{\mathbb R}$